# More efficient way to define a macro

Tags: macros

I want to write a macro to define some text, for example header title. User will use it like:

```
\headertitle{Some header for a document}
```

I wrote it this way:

```
\newcommand\Headertitle{Default header title}
\newcommand\headertitle[1]{\renewcommand\Headertitle{#1}}
```

And it used in `fancyhead` like this:

```
\fancyhead[CO]{-\thepage- \\* \Headertitle}
```

Everything works perfectly. If a user won't define his own header title, `Default header title` would be set.

Is there some more efficient way to write this macros, where I will not create two names for one command (like `\Headertitle` and `\headertitle` in my example?

Comment: That's more or less the approach that the standard classes take with `\title` or `\author`, so I would say it is standard practice. If the user is not supposed to ever need `\Headertitle` you can make it 'private' by using a name with `@` like `\shalom@headertitle`. Of course it would be possible to create a meta-command that sets up `\headertitle` and `\shalom@headertitle` with a default value with only one call (but the advantage of that approach only becomes visible if you have several such constructions).

Comment: I'm not sure what would really be bad about defining two macros, but I suppose you could use a token sequence instead. If you add `\newtoks\headertitle` to your preamble you can set the title with e.g. `\headertitle{My header title}` and use it with `\the\headertitle`. This involves just one control sequence and defines zero macros, but does use a `\toks` register

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of approaches.  Here's one where I define two data macros: `\headertitledefault` for the default header and `\theheadertitle` for the current header.  Then one command macro `\setheadertitle` that takes an optional header to set (or the default, if none specified).

But, as noted in comments, there is more than one "right" way to do this.  It is a matter of how you think of it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\newcommand\headertitledefault{Default header title}
\newcommand\setheadertitle[1][\headertitledefault]{\def\theheadertitle{#1}}
\setheadertitle
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\fancyhead[CO]{-\thepage- \\* \theheadertitle}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\clearpage
\setheadertitle[Some header for a document]
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is pretty much what the standard classes do for `\title` and `\author`, so I would say this is already a pretty solid solution (see §60.1 *The Title*, File F: `ltsect.dtx`, p. 386). Note that there is a difference between the approach of the standard styles and yours: Your definition of `\Headertitle` is local, the standard approach uses a global definition.

If your users are not supposed to use the value of `\Headertitle` anywhere in the document, you may want to consider making it into a 'private' macro with `@` in its name. That also avoids the internal name with a capital letter, of which I am not too fond (I prefer all-lowercase names).

You could define a meta-macro that defines the two commands for you. That is attractive if you expect to have to define several similar macros of this general form, but obfuscates stuff unnecessarily if you only use it for one command (as in the MWE).

With [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes)' [MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474710/35864)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\makeatletter
% {<name>}{<default value>}
\newcommand*{\shalom@maketitlelikecommand}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname shalom@#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname shalom@#1\endcsname{##1}}}

\shalom@maketitlelikecommand{headertitle}{Default header title}


\fancyhead[CO]{-\thepage- \\* \shalom@headertitle}
\makeatother

\headertitle{Loremm ipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\clearpage
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against this. What you can do is to define the second macro as a reserved one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\headertitle}{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\set@headertitle}{Default header title}%
}
\newcommand{\set@headertitle}[1]{\gdef\headertitle{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\headertitle

\headertitle{Real title}

\headertitle

\end{document}
```

Better is to have a `\setheadertitle` macro to be used in the preamble and `\headertitle` to be used in the document, after having been set with the former.

Comment: Or `\newcommand{\set@headertitle}[1]{\gdef\headertitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\set@headertitle}{#1}}}` (followed by `\set@headertitle{Default header title}`), so the user can change their mind mid-document :).